# method for copying into a new object while changing one or more proerties

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
const obj = {
  name: "foo",
  other: "something"
}
```

Creating a new object based on my object (a shallow copy) I would use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and then changing `name` on my new object:

```
const newObj =  {...obj}
newObj.name = "bar";
```

But recently I ran into syntax that also does the trick:

```
const newObj = {
  ...obj, name: "bar"
}
```

How does this work and what is it called?

Comment: a property ...?

Comment: It first copies all properties of obj then overrides the name property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two methods, you specified are equivalent. In the second method

```
const newObj = {
  ...obj, name: "bar"
}
```

It creates anothey key value pair with `key=name` and `value="bar"`, since 1 key cannot have multiple values (if its not an array). It overtires the previous value. Code in the second method is equivalent to

```
const newobj = {
  name: "foo",
  other: "something",
  name: "bar"
}
```

This is how [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) works, It allows allows an iterable to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected.

Answer (score 0):

This explains what it does. I hope it helps.
[image]

Comment: do you have a text instead of the image? it is hardly searchable. and not copyable.

Comment: https://oprea.rocks/blog/what-do-the-three-dots-mean-in-javascript/ This is the link

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating shallow copies, spread allows you to merge objects. The latter will override the former. For example:

```
const obj = { name: 'jane', age: 22 }
const merged = { ...obj, age: 21 } // { name: 'jane', age: 21 }

const obj = { name: 'jane', age: 22 }
const merged = { ...obj, hasDog: true } // { name: 'jane', age: 22, hasDog: true }

const obj = { name: 'jane', age: 22 }
const obj2 = { age: 19, hasDog: true }
const merged = { ...obj, ...obj2 } // { name: 'jane', age: 19, hasDog: true }
```

[MDN - Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)